# Java tutorial incomplete definition for an expression

Tags: java, expression

The Java tutorial for [expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) says that an

> expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations

Why are **literals** not included in this list?

Comment: A Javadoc is a specific documentation for an API. This is not Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Comment: The examples uses literals most than any of those. The tutorials are not intended to replace the Java Language Specification and include everything.

Comment: You're right. It's not Javadoc. Anyway it's an authoritative source, isn't it? That's where learners -especially novices - look for help.

Comment: It's just a tutorial. It's not meant to precisely define something. If you need a precise definition, lookup the JLS (Java Language Specification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) states:

> **15.8. Primary Expressions**
>
> Primary expressions include most of the simplest kinds of expressions,
> from which all others are constructed: ***literals***, class literals, field
> accesses, method invocations, and array accesses. A parenthesized
> expression is also treated syntactically as a primary expression.

That should be your starting point when looking for the definition or specification of all things java. A tutorial or some API documentation comment (thats what JavaDoc is) cannot be held against that same claim of completeness.